# Capturing multiple command outputs with Pexpect

Tags: python-2.7, pexpect

I am scripting for cisco devices using pexpect,

```
import pexpect
ssh_command = ' '
uname = ' '
pass = ' '
fout = file('logfile.txt','w')
child = pexpect.spawn (ssh_command)
print 'ssh initiated'
child.expect('.*name:')
child.sendline(uname)
child.expect('.*assword:')
child.sendline(pass)
child.expect('#')
child.sendline('sh ip int br')
child.logfile = fout
child.expect('#')
print(child.before)
child.sendline('sh hardware')
child.expect(['#',pexpect.EOF])
child.logfile = fout
fout.close()
```

For some reason, it issues the first command, I can see the output of the interfaces, however the script hangs there. When I exit the script it throws an error on

```
child.expect(['#',pexpect.EOF])
```

Cant seem to figure out why it stops there.

EDIT
The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 18, in <module>
    child.expect('#')
```

When I run this without the `print (child.before)` I do not see an output, but it works! it writes to the file.

Why does the script hang when I include the `print (child.before)` command?

Comment: unrelated: `child.expect('.*pattern')` is the same as just ``child.expect('pattern')``

Comment: see [how `pxssh` class handles the shell prompt](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pxssh.html?highlight=prompt#pexpect.pxssh.pxssh.prompt)

Comment: why do you see the output? Shouldn't it be captured by `pexpect`? Provide the full traceback and the actual code ([create a minimal example, to demonstrate the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: That is the actual code, apart form the username and password. It prints out the output of the first command but it deos not execute the second command

Comment: let's rephrase: do you see anything if you remove `print(child.before)`? Also, I don't see the full traceback in your question.

Comment: I do not see anything, but it prints it to the log file. Also, updated with the traceback

Comment: I don't see `pexpect.EOF` in the traceback. Also, still don't see the full traceback e.g., what is the type of the exception?